# how to get all the child elements in html using jQuery eq() extention?

Tags: jquery, html, children

I am not very good with jQuery and I have been working on a project and stuck in a problem regarding jQuery. I have a slider and its html structure is look like this:

```
<a class="slides" href="http://pvhorses.net/jersey/about-us/"><img src="http://pvhorses.net/jersey/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/front-pic-slide.jpg" alt="" class="change"></a>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){ 

//init js styles 
jQuery('body').addClass('hasJS'); 

// homepage cycles 
jQuery('#feature_gallery .bigimg').wrapAll('<div class="bigimgs">').parents('#feature_gallery').append('<ul class="menu" id="feature_gallery_pager">').cycle({ 
    fx:'fade', 
    easing: 'swing', 
    inDelay:    250, 
    drop:       40, 
    timeout:    5000, 
    pause:      true,
    slideExpr: '.bigimg',
    before:onBefore,
    pager:      '#feature_gallery_pager', 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    var img = jQuery(".slides").children().eq(0).attr("src");
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+img+'" class="thumb"><span></span></a></li>';  

    } 

});
```

Now I am trying to get the "src" attribute from the anchor link (a) with a class of slides and I am getting it pretty much but the problem is I am getting only the first element. I want to get the attr "src" from all the children elements of it.

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT?

Please help me and reply me as soon as you can.

Thank you,

Usman Ali Qureshi

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to map the elements and return the source attribute.
Then you can join the array into a comma seperated list or whatever you need ?

```
var img = jQuery.map( jQuery(".slides img"), function(_,slide) {
    return slide.src;
}).join(', ');
```

I'm guessing you're looking for something more like this :

```
var img = "";

jQuery(".slides img").each(function(_, slide) {
    img += '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+slide.src+'" class="thumb"><span></span></a></li>';
});

return img;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all sources to an array variable

```
var sources = new Array();
$("a.slides > img").each(function(index, value){
    sources.push($(value).attr("src"));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CT64M/)

**UPDATED**

getting gallery image src's :

```
var sourcesBig = new Array();
$("#slider .bigimgs  img").each(function (index, value) {
    sourcesBig.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

getting small pictures, from carousel :

```
var sourcesSmall = new Array();
$(".jcarousel-container  img").each(function (index, value) {
    sourcesSmall.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7s5Dt/10/)

Comment: when I tried your code with both $(value) and $(this), even the whole slider was gone.

Comment: The working slider is located on http://pvhorses.net/jersey/. Whenever I put <a> around the big image the images breaks and the src of the small images becomes something like this:

    <img src="undefined" class="thumb">

Comment: @UsmanAli don't wrap images in <a>, just use the code i updated